# How to map false color image to specific labels assigned for each color

Tags: python

I have a false color image which is shown below. I want to convert this image into an array where I can assign a label for each false color area. Thus I can access the image just using that label value.
I tried using

```
 r_channel = image[:, :, 0]
    g_channel = image[:, :, 1]
    b_channel = image[:, :, 2]
    label_map = (0.2989) * (r_channel) + (0.5870) * g_channel + (0.1140) * b_channel
    label_map = label_map * 500 / 255
    label_map = np.round(label_map).astype(int)
```

But the problem is that I get repeated labels in this case. I want each region to have a unique label, preferably in an ascending order starting from 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the unique way of getting labels. This is what I did:

```
    r_channel = image[:, :, 0]
    g_channel = image[:, :, 1]
    b_channel = image[:, :, 2]
    label_map = 1000000 * (r_channel) + 1000 * g_channel + b_channel
    label_map = np.round(label_map).astype(int)
```

Thus now I get unique labels for each superpixel region.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of values where non-zero values are considered "objects" and zeros as being "background", you can label the objects
using the [scipy.ndimage.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) function:

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

fname='/tmp/splotches.png'
arr = scipy.misc.imread(fname) 
print(arr.shape)
# (160, 240, 3)

r, g, b = np.rollaxis(arr, axis = -1)
label_map = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
label_map = label_map * 500 / 255
label_map = np.round(label_map).astype(int)
print(label_map.shape)
# (160, 240)

seen = set()
region = {}
i = 1
for val in label_map.flat:
    if val not in seen:
        seen.add(val)
        mask = (label_map == val)
        labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(mask) 
        for label in range(1, nr_objects+1):
            assert np.any(labeled==label)
            region[i] = labeled==label
            i += 1

print(len(region))
# 382
```

Using `scipy.ndimage.label`, 382 regions were found.

Comment: I think I didn't put my question clear enough. Actually, the problem I am facing is that the colors used in the map are all different corresponding to different regions. But when I am using the transformation `label_map = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
label_map = label_map * 500 / 255
label_map = np.round(label_map).astype(int)`
some colors which should be different get same value. I just don't want this to happen and I want all the regions to get a unique identifier.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but there might be a possibility that in label_map, some different regions have similar `0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b' value.
Thats why this conversion I believe is not correct. Check the answer that I have posted. And thanks for your help :)